# NSInputStream read:maxLength: cannot read data, returns -1

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsinputstream

In Objective C, I have somethng like this:

```
uint8_t f[400000];
NSString *Str;
unsigned int count = 0;
NSError* error = nil;
Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
@try {
    NSInputStream *fin = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:[Str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    count = [fin read:f maxLength:400000];

}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
@finally {
    NSLog(@"finally");
}
```

I am converting `nsstring` to `nsinputstream` and then trying to read the content

But after I debug the code, `count` has -1 in it, i.e an error occurred while reading. I don't understand what am I doing wrong here! Can someone please help me out.

**NOTE**: `Test.txt` is a plain text file with content as just "Hello" and debugging shows `Str` is initialised with the content. That means something is wrong in the `try` block.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I *believe* you need to set-up the delegate and schedule the input stream in the run loop ([see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html)).  Use `NSFileManager` instead.

Comment: yes it did the trick

Comment: Also creating an 400K `auto` variable is a bad idea ;-)

Comment: @Droppy but it is necessary in my case as the content of the file is huge. Anyways, what do you suggest?

Comment: Not using the stack.  Use `NSMutableData`.

Comment: Also your code example reads the file **name** not content into the input stream :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't open the stream. You cannot read from/write to a `NSStream` (`NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` are both subclasses of `NSStream`) without opening it first. Just call `open` on your stream object prior to reading from it.